# why it's works when I use a integer index but don't whit a i itterable variable inside a loop in Django template engine

Tags: python, html, django, loops, jinja2

this is gives a none values :

```
   {%for i in l%}
<tr>

  <td>{{con.hotel.i}}</td>
</tr>
{%endfor%}
```

while this works and give the correct values

```
  {%for i in l%}
<tr>
  <td>{{con.hotel1.0}}</td>
</tr>
{%endfor%}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it then will try to access the `.i` attribute. If you write `.item`, then it will first try to access `.item`, then `['item']` and finally try `[int('item')]`, so for `.0` that means it tries `.0` which fails, `['0']` which fails as well, and then `[int('0')]`, which will use the first item.

For `hotel.i`, it will thus first try `hotel.i`, then `hotel['i']`, and finally try to convert `'i'` to an `int`, which will all fail.

It would be confusing to also try `[item]`, since that would be confusing in case `.item` as attribute exists.

For *jinja* however, you can subscript, so:

```
{% for i in l %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ con.hotel[i] }}</td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: that returns an error : Could not parse the remainder: '[i]' from 'con.hotel[i]'

Comment: @MohamedChouai: then you are not using Jinja, but the Django template engine. The two are *not* the same (they look a bit similar). See https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#variables

Comment: I see 
actually I'm using Django template engine 
so what should I do?

Comment: @MohamedChouai: see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/templates/#configuration below the code fragment, it briefly discusses Jinja.